# Animating Auto Layout Constraints Not Working

Tags: ios, autolayout, uiviewanimation, ios-charts

*iOS 10, Swift 3.1*

I have a `UIView` called `graphPopup` inside a `UITableViewCell` that I'm trying to animate. Basically when someone taps a graph, a popup appears and I'd like it to animate its `x` and `y` into place.

Everything is working except the animation of the popup. Here's how it looks now:
[image]

I want the popup to **slide** from point-to-point into position. Here is my code:

```
class TotalCell: UITableViewCell, ChartViewDelegate{

  @IBOutlet weak var graphPopup: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var popupConstraintY: NSLayoutConstraint!
  @IBOutlet weak var popupConstraintX: NSLayoutConstraint!

  func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    //...
    graphPopup.isHidden = false

    //Set new auto layout constraints
    self.popupConstraintX.constant = highlight.xPx-44
    self.popupConstraintY.constant = highlight.yPx+18

    //Animate (which does nothing)   
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
      self.graphPopup.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
  }
}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? If I remove the animation bit entirely, it behaves the same way, but I know the animation is being called.

Any ideas?

Comment: Two questions - have you tried calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on `self`, insted of `graphPopup`? And second - where do you hide the popup? Have you tried keeping it visible all the time? It would be strange, but maybe the animation happens when it is not visible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `self.layoutIfNeeded()` instead of `self.graphPopup.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Comment: Strangely, I changed my view controller's appearance from `present` to `push` and animations worked.